# Remove username from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, text-mining

I have a list of lists regarding tweets and I need to remove the username.

```
[['@Hegelbon','That','heart','sliding','into','the','waste','basket','.',':('],['“','@ketchBurning',':','I','hate','Japanese','call','him','"','bani','"',
':(',':(','”','Me','too'], ... ]
```

The main problem is that I don't know how to work with a list of lists. I tried the following code among other things but did not work:

```
import re

    for element in tweets:
        for word in element:
            re.sub('@[^\s]+','', tweets)
```

Please help.

Comment: Rebuild the list with a list comprehension. `tweets = [['@Hegelbon','That','heart','sliding','into','the','waste','basket','.',':('], ['“','@ketchBurning',':','I','hate','Japanese','call','him','"','bani','"',
':(',':(','”','Me','too']]; filtered = [item for item in tweets if item[0] != '@Hegelbon']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to filter strings that starts with `@` (assuming your list of lists is stored as variable `l`):

```
[[i for i in s if not i.startswith('@')] for s in l]
```

This returns:

```
[['That', 'heart', 'sliding', 'into', 'the', 'waste', 'basket', '.', ':('], ['“', ':', 'I', 'hate', 'Japanese', 'call', 'him', '"', 'bani', '"', ':(', ':(', '”', 'Me', 'too']]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use list iterations:

```
mylist = [['@Hegelbon','That','heart','sliding','into','the','waste','basket','.',':('],['“','@ketchBurning',':','I','hate','Japanese','call','him','"','bani','"',
':(',':(','”','Me','too'] ]



newlist = [ [item for item in sublist if not item.startswith('@')] for sublist in mylist]
```